# regex: how to find two recurring “ char within a line

Tags: regex, replace, search-regex

I am having hundreds of lines as illustrated below, with more than one opening double-quote (**“**) occurring within almost every line as shown below:

```
... “ ...  “ ..... “ .....
```

**note**: those dots (...) above denote both words & spaces in this context for illustrative purposes.

1. How to search (via regex) for every such occurrence within every line? I tried achieving this with:

   `“.*“`  or, 
       `“.* “`

   but it is disappointingly returning even those who are proper i.e., with both opening & closing double quotes also (which is the correct way it should be) as follows:

   `... “ ...” ..... “ .....” ...... “ .....`
2. For every second `[space]“` recurring within every line it encounters — How to replace them (via regex) into `” [space]`?

Comment: @muhammad shahzad thanks for improving on the code bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `[^”]*` instead of `.*`, so it will search all occurence of two opening quotes with any character sequence in between **except** of closing qoute.

**EDIT:**

`“[^”]*?“` -- miss, that it will find largest srting between two opening quotes (*OQ*) as possible, in `“some text “more text “text` it will find `“some text “more text “`, so you need `?` after `*`.

---

And as of your pictures, you are using sublime, so replace `(“[^”]*?)\s“` with `\1”`

- `()` capturing a group, which you can access later with `\n`, where `n` is group number.
- `*?` lazy expression, stop at first occurence of next character (`\s` here)
- `\s` any whitespace character (space, tab, new line, etc.)
- `\1` first captured group, here - opening quote and some text

It is possible to use look behind `(?<=text)`, but it length must be known, in your exampole its length is unknown (because of `*`).

Comment: thank you so much! your solution is working wonderfully and it returned me 2190 such lines matching this criteria. Now, is there a way to make the replacement as I asked in the second question? For e.g., [this picture](https://i.snag.gy/LEUvx6.jpg) is one example of the results it returned; Of all these matches, what RegEx command should I type to replace **every alternate space followed by an opening double quote char** i. e., `[space] “` into `” [space]` as [this](https://i.snag.gy/J6An89.jpg) which is **a closing double-quote followed by space**?

Comment: added answer to second part.

Comment: Quoting you ❝ so replace `(“[^”]*?)\s“` with `\1” ` ❞ — End quote.
It is replacing the whole matched-string [e.g., as shown here](https://i.snag.gy/xk1sdj.jpg) to completely blank as [this](https://i.snag.gy/g0Kfod.jpg) instead of replacing it with (1) Closing-quote & (2)space, as explained in my question. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is strange, because `\1` is standard group defenition. And it works well in my sublime. But try to use `$1`, it is working too.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `s/(“.*?)(“)/`, you could replace every second occurrence of `“` into  `”` by  `r/(“.*?)(“)/$1”/g`

`.*?` as a lazy operator would make it stop right on the second occurrence.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, it doesn't work. Conversely, TEXHNIK's solution that he has given below works.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Since I am working on Sublime Text, therefore your codes, as you have provided, did not work (maybe it works for vim). However, after altering them to simply `(“.*?)(“)`, I just realised it's working! Yuppy. Furthermore, altering your replace solution to simply `$1”` works but it leaves a space which preceeds the closing-quote like this: `[space]”`. What I need in the replacement code is it should automatically shift the space after the closing quote, to this: `”[space]`. Is there a way to make that via RegEx?

Comment: Yeah just type it on your replace field